# Construction of Eilenberg-Maclane Space

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I have just learned about the construction of the Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(A,n)$ ($n \geq 1$). I am using [Hatcher's text](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf). He briefly describes the construction on p.365. I will recap the construction here:

> Choose a presentation $A = \langle a_{\alpha} | r_{\beta} \rangle$ (which exists since every group is a quotient of a free group, so the $a_{\alpha}$'s can be taken to be the generators of this free group with the $r_{\beta}$'s the generators of the kernel of the map from the free group to $A$). Define the CW complex $X_{n+1} = (\bigvee_{\alpha} S_{\alpha}^n) \cup_{\beta} e_{\beta}^{n+1}$, where the copies of $S^n$ are in bijection with the generators $a_{\alpha}$ of $A$ and the $(n+1)$-cells are glued corresponding to the relations $r_{\beta}$ of $A$. Then, $\pi_n(X_{n+1}) \cong A$, while $\pi_i(X_{n+1}) = 0$ for $i < n$ (which one can see by applying Proposition 1.26 of Hatcher's text in the n = 1 case, and using the Hurewicz Theorem for the case $n \geq 2$). Next, we attach $(n+2)$-cells to $X_{n+1}$ using cellular maps $S^{n+1} \rightarrow X^{n+1}$ that generate $\pi_{n+1}(X_{n+1})$ to form a space $X_{n+2}$ with $\pi_{n+1}(X_{n+2})$ trivial and $\pi_i(X_{n+2}) \cong \pi_i(X_{n+1})$ for $i \leq n$. Similarly, we attach $(n+3)$-cells to $X_{n+2}$ to form a space $X_{n+3}$ with $\pi_{n+2}(X_{n+3})$ trivial and $\pi_i(X_{n+3}) \cong \pi_i(X_{n+2})$ for $i \leq n+1$. We continue this process to obtain the desired CW complex $X = X_{\infty}$.

I have two questions about this construction:

- How can we see that $\pi_{n+1}(X_{n+2})$ is trivial? Are we choosing a presentation for the group $\pi_{n+1}(X_{n+1})$ and seeing how this group is affected once we attach $(n+2)$-cells to $X_{n+1}$ via the generators of this group? What's the importance of those maps being cellular?
- My instructor says that any construction he knows of $K(A,n)$ requires a colimit. I don't see one involved here. Does the colimit come in just in the last line above, to make the construction $X = X_{\infty}$ rigorous?

Thanks!

Comment: Intuitively you attach $n+1$ cells to kill the generators of $\pi_n$. By the cellular approximation theorem, any map of $S^n$ can be pushed into the $n$-skeleton, where it can be written as a product of the generators, and where it can then be null-homotoped away using the $n+1$ cells that were added. And yes, this construction is a colimit when you continue to infinity.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thanks! I'm trying to get this straight. $\pi_{n+1}(X_{n+2})$ consists of equivalence classes of maps $f:S^{n+1} \rightarrow X_{n+2}$. We need to show any such map is nullhomotopic. By cellular approximation, $f \simeq g$, where $g:S^{n+1} \rightarrow X_{n+2}$ has image in $X_{n+1}$. So, we can think of $g$ as a map $g:S^{n+1} \rightarrow X_{n+1}$. It can be written as a product of generators in $\pi_{n+1}(X_{n+1})$. How does $g$ become nullhomotopic now because of the $(n+2)$-cells that we added, though?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip It seems that the attaching maps of the $(n+2)$-cells we attach are precisely whatever the generators of $\pi_{n+1}(X_{n+1})$ are -- I'm just not seeing why that would make $g$, written as a product of those generators, nullhomotopic.

Comment: @michiganbiker88 the $(n+2)$ cells provide the track of the null-homotopy. Any map that lands in the boundary of a cell can be contracted to a point by pulling into that cell. You have to be careful with basepoints but that's the basic idea.